# Возможно ли создать тему WooCommerce c изначальной alethemes?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Наверно кто то знаком с фреймом для создания тем WordPress Alethemes
https://github.com/CRIK0VA/alethemes
Возможно в связке с данным фреймворком делать тему для WooCommerce?

Answer (score 0):

Тему c поддержкой WooCommerce можно создать хоть с нуля. Нет никаких причин предполагать, что указанный вами framework будет несовместим с WooCommerce. Для декларирования поддержки WooCommerce вашей темой надо следовать простым правилам, описанным в [официальном руководстве](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/).